# Capture the error output from a stored procedure when calling another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Sorry for the long question title, but I have a stored procedure which is being called by some business objects and it's working fine.  I want to extend this stored procedure to call a new stored procedure (basically it will insert some of the passed in data into another table), but this isn't working.  How can I get the error output back from both stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proc that calls the first proc store the error code in an output parameter, in the second proc the return will be the error code and then the output parameter will hold the value of the return value of the proc that it called

Hope that this is clear

example that you can run

```
--first proc
create proc prtest
as
return @@error
go

--2nd proc, which calls the 1st
create proc prtest2 @error int output
as
exec @error = prtest
return @@error
go

--call 2nd proc and show both statuses
declare @iReturn int, @iOutput int
exec @iReturn = prtest2 @error = @iOutput output

select @iReturn,@iOutput
```